# Adding an click icon only to li element who is a div next element

Tags: jquery, menu, containers, jquery-selectors, toggle

i have a vertical menu structure, the structure i can't change to like nested elements.
But i have to solve minimal issues to finish my vertical menu.

FIRST: (important):::
i am trying to show a toggle icon (img plus.gif) after each li element WHO is div tag the next element.
If the li element doesn't have a DIV tag as next element so no icon is should be displayed.

At this moment i wrote a jQuery code that adding a toggle icon on EVERY li element. (after li)
But that is wrong. What is wrong in my jquery code?

SECOND:
How to replace the toggle icon (plus.gif) to (minus.gif) if this container is already opened?

THIRD: 
How to auto collapse previos opened div container by toggle another parent div container??

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/croman91/B5Qf8/3/

Here is my jquery code:

Thanks for minimal Helping.  :-D

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.firstLevel div').hide();

    $('li.menuItem').each(function() {
if ($( this ).next('div').length > 0) {
$( "li.menuItem" ).after( "<img class='sub2Opener' src='http://s14.directupload.net/images/131108/fbrluvti.gif' />" );
}
});

    $('li.menuSub2Item').each(function() {
if ($( this ).next('div').length > 0) {
$( "li.menuSub2Item" ).after( "<img class='sub2Opener' src='http://s14.directupload.net/images/131108/fbrluvti.gif' />" );
}
});

    $(".sub1Opener").click(function() {
$(this).next('div').slideToggle();
});

    $(".sub2Opener").click(function() {
$(this).next('div').slideToggle();
});

});
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't/shouldn't work. Putting `div`s in a `ul` is a flagrant violation of the HTML spec, which states that only `li`s shall appear as direct children of `ul`s.

Comment: i knowing that is not a valid HTML, but i have not another solution, what i can do is to rename all li and ul elements to div container, but i have no idea to get this to work. The most important issue solve would be for me to show the icons only if element li has a div as next element. But my function produce it on every li element. ANy Idea?

Comment: I'll try and work on a solution later; I'll get back to you (if someone else doesn't find one in the meantime, of course).

Comment: thank you very much for helping. So now i solved one issue. I added this: (.siblings("div").hide(1000);) to the toggle function to auto close a opened div container. So 2 issues remainig